# Display another message if Exception isn't caught in Try Catch C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to have it display another message only if an Exception isn't caught when using Try Catch. Right now it'll display an exception, and then my message after that. So I was just asking for some tips on how I could go about doing that.

Here's my code.

```
try
        {


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Solution Downloaded in C:/dwnload/working");
        }
```

Comment: place it outside of the `try`?

Comment: @Gaterde - no, then it would show always as well

Comment: I guess like the answer below placing it inside the try at the bottom should work because if it hasn't hit any exceptions by that point it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    try
    {
         // Do Work

         // when we get here: success! Without errors!
         MessageBox.Show("Solution Downloaded in C:/dwnload/working");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should just do it after the code that can throw an exception in the `try` statement.

```
try
{
    // do operation that could throw exception
    // display message
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // catch code
}
finally
{
    // code to run at the end regardless of success/failure
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple refactor the message as a variable. Assign the success message at the end of the try block.

in the catch block, assign the error message.

Then display the MessageBox, in the finally block or after, as you prefer.

```
    string message;
    try
    {

         // at the end of try block
         message = "Solution Downloaded in C:/dwnload/working);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         message = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        // in general, keep the finally code as the minimum needed for sanity cleanup. 
    }

    // If you rethrow your exception, and still want to show the message box, then might have a reason for wanting this instruction back inside the finally block. 
    MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: exactly i agree with you. Finally is for important cleanup that *must* be done Actually, I started writing this answer with the message box outside. *But* it would not display message box if the exception is rethrown, this code might be an oversimplification of what's actally in the catch block . So i put it back inside the finally block, the time to write a remark on that